# Overextended vertical lines in table

Tags: tables, vertical

Any help why are the first two vertical lines over extended please?

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage[tagged, highstructure]{accessibility}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdflang={en-GB},
pdftitle={Teaching Shedule},
pdfauthor={Dr },
pdfsubject={Mathematics},
pdfkeywords={Accessibility, LaTeX},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\usepackage{tagging}

\title{\vspace{-3.0cm}\textbf{\huge{Mathematics 1} \\ \textbf{\large{Approximate Weekly Teaching Schedule}}}}
\author{}
\date{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\vspace{-10mm}
For approximate teaching schedule see also ...
\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{ V{4} c|c|c|c V{4} } 
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
\makecell{\textbf{Trimester and}  \\ \textbf{ Week Number}}  & \textbf{Topic}                     & \textbf{Exrecise}    & \textbf{Coursework} \\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
Tri-A W01                 & Algebra                            & 1-7 p.12-15           &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W02                 & Algebra                            & \makecell{1-9 p.28-31; \\ 4.6 p.43} &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W03                 & Functions                          & 1-3 p.58              &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W04                 & Functions                          & \makecell{3-5 p.58-59; \\ 1-3 p.86} & \makecell{Approximately \\ Test 1 Issued} \\
\hline
Tri-A W05                 & Functions                          & 4-6 p.87              &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W06                 & Logarithmic Scale                  & 7-14 p.87-88          &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W07                 & Complex Numbers                    & 1-7 p.119-121         &   \\
\hline
Tri-A W08                 & Complex Numbers                    & 8-28 p.121-124        &  \makecell{Approximately \\ Test 2 Issued} \\
\hline
Tri-A W09                 & Trigonometry                       & 1-7 p.167-169         &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W10                 & Trigonometry                       & 8-9 p.169-170         &  \\
\hline
Tri-A W11                 & Trigonometry                       & 9-11 p.170-171        &  \makecell{Approximately \\ Test 3 Issued} \\
\hline
Tri-A W12                 & Matrix Algebra                     & 1-9  p.185-189        &  \\
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
Tri-B W01                 & Vectors                            & 1-9 p.22-23           &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W02                 & Vectors                            & 11-38 p.23-27         &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W03                 & Differentiation                    & 1-12 p.52-55          &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W04                 & Differentiation                    & 1-12 p.52-55          &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W05                 & Differentiation                    & 1-12 p.52-55          &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W06                 & Differentiation                    & 1-12 p.52-55          &  \makecell{Approximately \\ Test 4 Issued} \\
\hline
Tri-B W07                 & Integration                        & 1-7 p.92-94           &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W08                 & Integration                        & 1-7 p.92-94           &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W09                 & Integration                        & 1-7 p.92-94           &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W10                 & Integration                        & 1-7 p.92-94           &  \\
\hline
Tri-B W11                 & Numerical Methods                  & 1-7 p.107-108         & \\
\hline 
Tri-B W12                 & Revision  for Exam              &                       & \\ 
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth} 
\end{tabular}



\vspace{1mm}
\subsubsection*{ RD    $ 2023 $}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reduced your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

If you remove the option `tagged` from package `accessibility` it works correctly. So this option seems to lead to unwanted side effects. If you need it, you could take a look at the documentation. If there is no solution for this, you can create an issue on the related GitHub page.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tagged, highstructure]{accessibility} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{  c|c } 
    a & b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### MWE without `tagged`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[highstructure]{accessibility} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{  c|c } 
    a & b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the `tagged` option, but write:

```
a & b
```

or

```
a & b\par
```

Comment: But than you can't make a `\hline` at the end, as the OP as in the question.